# $y^2=x^3+7$ has an integral soln. trivial issues that are imposing me from understanding a proof from a book.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have some trivial issues that are imposing me from understanding a proof from a book.

(i) if $y^2=8k^3+7$ where $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ $\implies$ $y^2\equiv7 \,[8]$ which is not possible, because $(\frac{7}{8})=-1$. **But can someone tell me an easy way to interpret why 
$(\frac{7}{8})=-1$?**

(ii) if $x$ is odd then I know why $(x-1)^2+3\equiv3 \,[4]$, **but why does this imply that exists prime $p$ st $p|(x-1)^2+3\equiv3 \, [4]$** where $p\equiv3 \, [4]$? (according to book, otherwise all its prime factors are 1 modulo 4 $\implies$ $(x-1)^2+3\equiv1 \, [4]$) fair enough, **but why does this $\implies$ $(x-1)^2+3\not\equiv3 \, [4]$?**

**can a number not be congruent 1  [4] and 3  [4] simultaneously?**

**And does it have to be congruent to at least one of these?**

(iii) $p\equiv3 \, [4]$ $\implies$  $(\frac{-1}{p})=-1$ ?

(iv) if $y^2=x^3+7$ has an integral soln. (which it does not) then $x$ has to be odd and $y$ even, **why is $y$ necessarily even?**

(v) $y^2=x^3+7$ reducing equation modolu $4$ $\implies$ $0\equiv(x+3) \,[4]$ I see what they have done, e.g. $7\equiv3 \, [4]$ so 7 becomes 3.

**how can we prove that $0\equiv(x+3) \, [4]$ is even true?**

(vi) $x$ odd and $x+2>0$ and $x+2\equiv3 \, [4]$ $\implies$ it has prime factor $p\equiv3 \, [4]$
**why?**

thanks a bunch

Comment: It is so much easier when you write $y^2 + 1 = x^3 + 8.$ See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/330779/solve-y2-x3-33-in-integers/330806#330806 including my comment about $a^2 + b^2$

Comment: The explanation $\left(\frac{7}{8}\right)=-1$ is a strange way to put it. The author is using the Jacobi symbol, a generalization of the Legendre symbol. But it would be much easier to say that $7$ is of the form $4k+3$, so cannot be a perfect square.

Comment: What Book? ${}{}{}$

Comment: As for iii), $\displaystyle \left(\frac{-1}{p}\right) = (-1)^{(p-1)/2} = 1 \iff p \equiv 1\ (4)$ for odd $p$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following address your specific questions:

The explanation $\left(\frac{7}{8}\right)=-1$ is a strange way to put it. The author seems to be  using a non-standard variant of the Jacobi symbol to indicate that a certain quadratic congruence is not solvable. It would have been much clearer to say that $7$ is of the form $4k+3$, so cannot be a perfect square.

A number certainly cannot be simultaneously congruent to $1$ and to $3$ modulo $4$: it cannot have simultaneously remainder $1$ and remainder $3$ on division by $4$. Any **odd* number is congruent to exactly $1$ or $3$ modulo $4$.

For your next question, we cannot have $x$ even. For if $x$ is even then $x^3$ is divisible by $8$, so $x^3+7$ is congruent to $3$ modulo $4$, and therefore cannot be a square. Thus $x$ is odd. It follows that $x^3$ is odd, so $x^3+7$ is even. Thus $y^2$ is even, which forces $y$ to be even.

The notation now gets hard to read. But I think you are asking at the end why a positive integer which is congruent to $3$ modulo $4$ must have a prime factor which is congruent to $3$ modulo $4$. So suppose that $b\equiv 3\pmod{4}$, where $b$ is positive. We can assume that $b\gt 1$. Any product of two numbers congruent to $1$ modulo $4$ is itself congruent to $1$ modulo $4$. But $m$ can be expressed as a product of (not necessarily distinct) primes. If these were all congruent to $1$ modulo $4$, then their product $m$ would also be congruent to $1$ modulo $4$. But it isn't.

Comment: thanks for this, just small add on: ''A number certainly cannot be simultaneously congruent to 1 and to 3 modulo 4: it cannot have simultaneously remainder 1 and remainder 3 on division by 4''   if x cong. 1 and 3 mod 4 then this implies x is even (is does there exist such an x?), but the converse is false e.g. x=2.

Comment: sorry I get it. If x is cong. 1 and 3 mod 4 (this implies x is even) but x is odd by assumption.

Comment: In symbols, if we had $x\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ and $x\equiv 3\pmod{4}$, then we would have $3\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, so $2\equiv 0\pmod{4}$, which is false. If $a\equiv 0\pmod 4$ then $a\equiv 0\pmod{2}$, but the converse does not hold. I think that is what you are saying above, and it is true. Maybe thinking in terms of remainders is more concrete.

Answer (score 1):

Here, I will try to be as explicit as possible to show that $y^2=x^3+7$ has no integer solution.

Case 1: Suppose that $x$ is even, so $x=2k$.  It follows that $y^2=8k^3+7$.  This implies that $y^2\equiv 7\mod 8$.  This is a contradiction because there is no $y$ such that $y^2\equiv 7\mod 8$.  You can check this by squaring the numbers $0,1,\ldots,7$, and showing that none of them give a remainder of $7$ when you divide by $8$.

Case 2: Suppose that $x$ is odd.  Notice that $x^3+7$ will be even, so that $y$ must also be even (else $y^2=x^3+7$ will be odd).  Note that $x^3\equiv x\mod 4$ (check this for $x=1,3$), $y^2\equiv 0\mod 4$ (because $y$ is even), and $7\equiv 3\mod 4$.  Thus, reducing our equation mod $4$ gives the equation $0\equiv (x+3)\mod 4$, or $x\equiv 1\mod 4$.

Now write $y^2+1=x^3+8=(x+2)(x^2-2x+4)$.  Since $x+2\equiv 3\mod 4$, there must exist some prime $p\equiv 3\mod 4$ dividing $x+2$.  This follows from the fact that all odd numbers are congruent to either $1$ or $3\mod 4$, and the product of two numbers congruent to $1\mod 4$ is also congruent to $1\mod 4$.  Then for this prime $p$ we can write $y^2+1\equiv 0\mod p$.  This is impossible by [quadratic reciprocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity).

Hence, no integer solutions exist.