# $x^3-9=y^2$ find integral solutions

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, mordell-curves

Find all integral solutions

$x^3-9=y^2$

I tried many times but still no idea how to solve it. I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 5):

The elliptic curve of type $y^2=x^3-n$ is called [Mordell curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordell_curve). For $n=9$ it has no integral solutions, see [here](http://oeis.org/A081121). Some of the cases can be solved by considering it modulo $4$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222093/show-that-the-equation-y2-x3-7-has-no-integral-solutions?rq=1), for the case $x^3+7=y^2$. Note that $7\equiv -9 \bmod 4$.